# Getting Error Code When Trying to Run Javascript via Python Wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I am trying to click a link via Javascript (wrapped up in Python)

The item I am trying to click is this:

```
<a href="/node/1742957/nodequeue">Nodequeue</a>
```

And my coworker was suggesting I use this:

```
br.runjs("""jQuery(\"a:contains(\'Nodequeue\')\").trigger(\"click\");""")
```

Which runs the following Javascript code:

```
jQuery("a:contains('Nodequeue')").trigger("click");
```

But which then gives me the following error, over and over and over again:

```
Javascript console (:1): Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://cdn.nprove.com/cpma/p/1/2/e/b/12ebf3bc368ry3ra.html?npuid=1310010225&rurl=&id=cpma-2n7eypbvio581300288437193&null=&r=366424962878227 from frame with URL http://www.benzinga.com/analyst-ratings/analyst-color/11/07/1742957/the-beef-stops-here. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Any idea what's going on? I am just trying to navigate to the page indicated in the link listed above.

Comment: In your description, it's not clear what you mean by "wrapped up in Python".  Python doesn't have native support for HTML or JavaScript, so you must be using libraries of some kind or another.  You should post more of your python code before anyone will be able to help.